# Nested Custom Taxonomies | Incorrect posts when querying

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I have two custom Taxonomies in wordpress which have posts attached to them, like the following example:

**Taxanomy A

Taxanomy B**
Post 1
Post 2

Each post have the two taxonomies attached to it depends the need. I need to output that for every Taxonomy A there is Taxanomy B and for every Taxonomy B there X number of posts.

I want to achieve this in arrays to eventually output then in a JSON format and this is what I managed to write up and working however, the results are not correct:

```
$TaxanomiesA = get_terms("TaxanomyA", array('hide_empty' => false));
$TaxanomiesB = get_terms("TaxanomyB", array('hide_empty' => false));

$TaxanomyAArray = array();
$TaxanomyBArray = array();
$postssArray = array();

foreach($TaxanomiesA as $TaxanomyA) {
        $TaxanomyAArray[] = array (  
        'id' => $TaxanomyA->term_id,
        'name' => $TaxanomyA->name,
        'TaxanomyB' => $TaxanomyBArray
    );

    $args = array(//Arguments);
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

        foreach($TaxanomiesB as $TaxanomyB){
                $TaxanomyBArray[] = array (  
                        'id' => $TaxanomyB->term_id,
                        'name' => $TaxanomyB->name,
                        'posts' => $postssArray
                    );
            foreach($posts as $post){
                    $postssArray[] = array (  
                        'id' => $post->ID,
                        'name' => $post->title
                    );
            }

        }

    }  

    $jsonOutput=array(
        'JSON' => $TaxanomyAArray
    );

    echo json_encode($jsonOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);                                            

}
```

This is the output I want to achive:

```
{
   "JSON":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "name":"TaxonomyA Name",
         "Taxonomy":[
            {
               "id":"1",
               "name":"TaxonomyB Name",
               "posts":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "name":"Post Title"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "name":"Post Title 2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: AFAIK taxonomies cannot be related to each other, besides parent-child relationships in a single hierachical taxonomy. Besides that, can you give an example of the data that you have, and an example of the output you want? (with both positive examples: post in taxonomy term 1 is listed - and negative: post in taxonomy term 2 is not listed)

Comment: @guiniveretoo - I have updated the post with the expected output I want to achieve. My problem Is I am nearly there but posts are getting repeated due to the array being in the foreach loop

Comment: So, to clarify, for each top-level term (A), you want to loop through the child terms (B). For each of **those** child terms, you want to loop through posts categorized in that term. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Is it possible to need more than two levels of taxonomy terms? As in, A->B-->C?

Comment: @guiniveretoo - no more than two level of taxonomies, so yeas as you said I need to get all the posts who have taxonomy B and taxonomy A

Comment: And where are there repeated posts?

Comment: @guiniveretoo - do you have skype or something where I can try explain to you a bit further ?

Comment: @guiniveretoo - each post is getting repeated for every taxonomy B

Comment: I think you're skipping something in the code that you have posted above. anyway, the issue is that the `get_posts` function is being called outside of the `$TaxanomiesB` loop. Move it inside and make sure the current `$TaxanomyB` is being used in the `$args` in `get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `get_posts` function is being called outside of the `$TaxanomiesB` loop. Move it inside and make sure the current `$TaxanomyB` is being used in the $args in `get_posts`.

Add data to `$TaxanomyAArray` and `$TaxanomyBArray` at the end of each for-each loop, otherwise the first object in the array will just be empty.

You also need to re-initialze the `$array` variables at the start of each parent loop, otherwise you'll end up with repeats of each post/taxonomy multiple times per set (like `'a' => (1 => (foo, bar), 2 => (foo, bar, foo, bar)), 'b' => 1 => (foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar)` ...etc).

```
$TaxanomiesA = get_terms("TaxanomyA", array('hide_empty' => false));
$TaxanomiesB = get_terms("TaxanomyB", array('hide_empty' => false));

$TaxanomyAArray = array();

foreach($TaxanomiesA as $TaxanomyA) {
    $TaxanomyBArray = array();
    foreach($TaxanomiesB as $TaxanomyB){
        $args = array(//Arguments with $TaxonomyB);
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        $postsArray = array();
        foreach($posts as $post){
            $postsArray[] = array (  
                'id' => $post->ID,
                 'name' => $post->title
            );
        }
        $TaxanomyBArray[] = array (  
            'id' => $TaxanomyB->term_id,
            'name' => $TaxanomyB->name,
            'posts' => $postsArray
        );
    }

    $TaxanomyAArray[] = array (  
        'id' => $TaxanomyA->term_id,
        'name' => $TaxanomyA->name,
        'TaxanomyB' => $TaxanomyBArray
    );
}  

$jsonOutput = array(
     'JSON' => $TaxanomyAArray
);

echo json_encode($jsonOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```